# pip install pyttsx3 throws error python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, pip, pyttsx

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install pyttsx3
Collecting pyttsx3
  Using cached pyttsx3-2.80-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting pyobjc>=2.4
  Using cached pyobjc-6.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 kB)
Collecting comtypes; "win32" in sys_platform
  Using cached comtypes-1.1.7.zip (180 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==6.1; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Downloading pyobjc_framework_AppleScriptObjC-6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN==6.1; platform_release >= "10.0"
  Using cached pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN-6.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zecnttcs\\pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zecnttcs\\pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zecnttcs\pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zecnttcs\pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zecnttcs\pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
        for fn in os.listdir("Modules")
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zecnttcs\pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN\pyobjc_setup.py", line 408, in Extension
        os_level = get_os_level()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zecnttcs\pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN\pyobjc_setup.py", line 218, in get_os_level
        pl = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist")
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\plistlib.py", line 99, in readPlist
        with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\plistlib.py", line 82, in _maybe_open
        with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Whenever i try to run `pip install pyttsx3` the previous error is shown. I am fully updated with Setuptools and have followed multiple trouble shooting steps. My last step is to post here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using python-3x version there for use this

```
pip3 install pyttsx3
```

If you use conda environment install this using anaconda prompt.

```
conda install -c auto pyttsx
```